# migrating website from hostgator to hostinger im getting black page i check both php version they are ok

Tags: php, migration, host

Migrating my website from old host to new one and i am getting blank page i upload all the files through ftp. I check PHP version. same version. I check both version. They are in same version not working.

Comment: not "black" should be "blank" page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't really provided enough information her. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: never mind its working. you can close this question

Comment: Please delete it yourself, I don't have that power :)